# projection of a vector onto a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, projection

supppose that we have a vector space $$A=\left(\left[
\begin{array}{}
  x\\
  y\\
  w\\
  z\\
\end{array}
\right] 
: x-y+w=0 \right)$$ and we wanted to find the closest point to a vector 
$$x=
\left[\begin{array}{}
  a\\
  b\\
  c\\
  d\\
\end{array}\right]
$$
I solved the problem by finding the basis of the vector space A and orthonormalizing it, then taking the projection of x onto the orthonormal basis of A which returned a vector. However I would like a second method to verify that this is in fact the closest point. Is there a way to verify whether or not my solution is correct?

Comment: Once you have an orthonormal basis of $A$, say $e_1,e_2,e_3$ you can express an arbitrary point of $A$ as $te_1+ue_2+ve_3$ and compute $(x-(te_1+ue_2+ve_3))^2$, then take it to the minimum.

Comment: working the real space would the minimization occur when the interior portion is equal to zero. Also its squared because  you are projecting the distance between x and an arbitrary point on itself right?

Comment: You could’ve saved yourself a lot of work by projecting orthogonally onto $A^\perp$ instead, which is only one-dimensional, and then subtracting that from $x$. You can read a vector that spans $A^\perp$ directly from the equation that defines $A$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes: if $p\in A$, then $p$ is the point of $A$ closest to $x$ if and only if $x-p$ is orthogonal to every element of $A$.

For instance, the solution of your problem is$$p=\begin{bmatrix}\frac13(2a+b-c)\\\frac13(a+2b+c)\\\frac13(-a+b+2c)\\d\end{bmatrix}$$and$$x-p=\begin{bmatrix}\frac13(a-b+c)\\\frac13(-a+b-c)\\\frac13(a-b+c)\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$And, indeed, if $x$, $y$, $w$, and $z$ are such that $x-y+w=0$, then$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\w\\z\end{bmatrix}.(x-p)=0.$$

Comment: interesting I know that the shortest point from a plane to a point is always when there exists an orthogonal relationship, but what is the intuition behind this?

Comment: and thanks alot!!

Comment: Imagine a point $(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3$. It's projection into the $z=0$ plane is $(x,y,0)$. And $(x,y,z)-(x,y,0)=(0,0,z)$, which is orthogonal to every element of the plane $z=0$.